# Encrypt Data in Play Session Cookie

Tags: scala, cookies, encryption, playframework-2.0, session-cookies

I am storing a few small pieces of user data in the Play! session cookie in order to achieve a state-less server. There are four pieces of data. I want to encrypt two of them for security purposes. I'm using the Play Crypto library. Encryption looks like this (assume `encryptKey` is a valid 16-byte string):

```
Redirect(successRedirectURL).withSession("id" -> (userProfile.get \ "_id").as[String],
                                         "name" -> Crypto.encryptAES(name, encryptKey),
                                         "imageUrl" -> { if (imageUrl.isEmpty) "" else imageUrl.get },
                                         "email" -> Crypto.encryptAES((userProfile.get \ "email").as[String]))
```

Decryption looks like this:

```
def getUserName[A](implicit request: SecuredRequest[A]): String = Crypto.decryptAES(request.session.get("name").get, encryptKey)
def getUserEmail[A](implicit request: SecuredRequest[A]): String = Crypto.decryptAES(request.session.get("email").get, encryptKey)
```

Now, the user name decrypts just fine. The email does not. I've directly fed in encrypted strings to verify that it is not the session mechanism and I got the same behavior. The stacktrace I get when I call `getUserEmail` is this:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:165) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:162) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:185) [scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313) ~[na:na]
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087) ~[na:1.7.0_10]
    at play.api.libs.Crypto$.decryptAES(Crypto.scala:229) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.libs.Crypto.decryptAES(Crypto.scala) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
```

I was trying to figure out how to set it not to do padding, but I couldn't figure out values for `application.crypto.provider` or `application.crypto.aes.transformation` in my application.conf that work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your encryption:

```
Redirect(successRedirectURL).withSession("id" -> (userProfile.get \ "_id").as[String],
                                     "name" -> Crypto.encryptAES(name, encryptKey),
                                     "imageUrl" -> { if (imageUrl.isEmpty) "" else imageUrl.get },
                                     "email" -> Crypto.encryptAES((userProfile.get \ "email").as[String]))
```

I see that the **encryptAES** for **email** doesn't pass **encryptKey**, as done for **name**.

Is that a typo, or related to your problem?

Try:

```
"email" -> Crypto.encryptAES((userProfile.get \ "email").as[String]), encryptKey)
```